# Как отправить okhttp https запрос с собственным сертификатом?

Tags: java, https, ssl, okhttp

Имеется задача выполнить https запрос с собственным сертификатом .crt
Как, с помощью библиотеки okhttp на java отправить https запрос подписанным собственным сертификатом?